# UIWebView does not open link in iphone app

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have UIWebView i want to load link in it but it does not show any thing here is the code which i am using it does not show

fileName has value http://www.google.com

```
            NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:fileName];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    [webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: Try with my edited answer

Comment: @native bellow all answer is perfect check first your webView is connected or not with IBOutlate..? from xib.

Comment: @NitinGohel Not getting why you are telling this to me. I have also asked the same thing in my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try like this,replace `fileURLWithPath` with `URLWithString`

```
    NSString *fileName= @"http://www.google.com";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [webview setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    [webview loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: @ Native Developer:then check your IBOutlet connection.

Comment: @ Native Developer:max problem is in IBOutlet connection if your webview created by programatically then check your frames.

Answer (score 0):

`**fileURLWithPath**` is used when there is a path containing your URL.

But in your case there is a direct URL so you should use like following

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@"http://www.google.com"]];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Comment: if this also doesn't work, then let me know how you have taken webView. I mean from xib or programatically

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create a URL String.
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.google.com"];
//Create a Legeal URL object.
NSURL *MyUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
//URL Requst Object
NSURLRequest *requestObj = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:MyUrl];
// set Fit page to WebView
[webView setScalesPageToFit:YES];
//Load the request in the UIWebView.    
[webView loadRequest:requestObj];
```

**NOTE :** Don't forget to Add `webView` to `self.View` **OR** if you add with `XIB` then make sure you connection is proper;

Answer (score 0):

Try this ..... !!!

```
 UIWebView * aWebView = [[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
    NSString *fileName= @"http://click-labs.com";

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileName];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [aWebView setScalesPageToFit:YES];

    [aWebView loadRequest:request];
    [ self.view addSubview:aWebView];
```